# Cordova - How to POST (upload to server) image picked with ImagePicker?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I use Cordova ImagePicker plugin to pick image from the phone gallery. It returns the image file URI. How do I send that image to server based on its URI path?

```
pickImage() {
    ImagePicker.getPictures({maximumImagesCount: 1}).then(
        results => {
            results.map(file_uri => {
                console.log('GOT FILE URI: ' + file_uri);
                // SEND FILE TO SERVER
            });
        }, err => {
        }
    );
}
```

Tried but failed:

- **FileTransfer** plugin. It is supposed to upload the image to an endpoint based on the local URI path. But it didn't work for me and fails in silence.
- **File** plugin. It is supposed to be able to read the local file and return the binary, which I can then POST to server. But it doesn't read the file and fails in silence for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Base64](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-base64) plugin seem to work fine. It gets the base64 string from the image URI path, which can then be POSTed to server.

**Sample client code** - JavaScript (ES6):

```
pickImage() {
    ImagePicker.getPictures({maximumImagesCount: 1}).then(
        results => {
            results.map(file_uri => {
                console.log('GOT FILE URI: ' + file_uri);
                window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile(file_uri, base64 => {
                    // POST base64 string to server;
                }, error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
            });
        }, error => {
            console.error(error);
        }
    );
}
```

**Sample server code** inside POST handler - Python:

```
import base64
...
def post(self, filename):
    b64string = self.request.body.decode()
    b64data = b64string.split(',')[1]
    binary = base64.b64decode(b64data)
    with open('/path/to/images/' + filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(binary)
```

**Extra** - If you need to get the binary of just need to use the File API, you can create a Blob like so ([source](https://gist.github.com/fupslot/5015897)):

```
base64toBlob(base64string) {
    var byteString = atob(base64string.split(',')[1]);
    var mimeString = base64string.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var bb = new Blob([ab], {type: 'image/jpeg'}); // your mime type here
    return bb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use  outputType: 1

```
        let options = {
        maximumImagesCount: 8,
        quality: 100,
        outputType: 1
    }
    ImagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            this.uploadImage(results[i]);
        }
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
```